# How to test if an object is any type of array or list?

Tags: arrays, list, powershell, type-testing

I want to test if an object is a string or any type of array or list (not hashtable or dictionary, etc.)  It seems impossible to test for every type of collection in .NET.  I must be missing some ICollection type.

I have tried something like:

```
($list -is [Collections.IEnumerable]) -and ($list -isnot [Collections.IDictionary])
```

But a stack or queue would return true in that test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically a `hashtable` and other Dictionary types are Collections. `Queue` and `Stack` are also Collections, they implement the [`ICollection` interafce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1?view=net-7.0).

The interface you could target in this case, if I understood correctly what you're looking for, is [`IList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist?view=net-7.0). `array`, `ArrayList`, `List<T>` and other *collection types* have this interface in common:

```bash
$instancesToTest = (
    @(),
    @{},
    [ordered]@{},
    [System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[string]]::new(),
    [System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection[string]]::new(),
    [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new(),
    [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string, string]]::new(),
    [System.Collections.Generic.Queue[string]]::new(),
    [System.Collections.Generic.Stack[string]]::new(),
    [System.Collections.Stack]::new(),
    [System.Collections.Queue]::new(),
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
)

$instancesToTest | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Type    = $_.GetType()
        IsIList = $_ -is [System.Collections.IList]
    }
} | Sort-Object IsIList -Descending
```

There is also a great module you can use called [ClassExplorer](https://github.com/SeeminglyScience/ClassExplorer) to find all types implementing this interface:

```bash
Find-Type -ImplementsInterface System.Collections.IList
```

Comment: Thanks for the `ClassExplorer` tip. Note that it conveniently supports tab-completion; e.g., `Find-Type -ImplementsInferface IList<tab>` completes to `Find-Type -ImplementsInterface System.Collections.IList` (and using a type-name _string_ is sufficient).